# Why is my regex expression failing?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

I'm using Python pandas to merge two datasets on a column named 'title'. Some of the data, in one dataset has additional characters in the title cells surrounded by parentheses which causes the merge to fail on these cells. I'm trying to remove the parentheses and the values they contain using the following however, the merge still misses the updated data.

Data sample, code and regex are below.

I'm assuming that the regex is incorrect - any thoughts?

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a12bcde0'], 'title': ['company_a']})

data2 = pd.DataFrame({'serial_number': ['01a2b345','10ab2030'],'title':['company_a','company_a (123)']}) 

data2['title'].replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace=r"\(.*\)",value=r'')

pd.merge(data1, data2, on='title')
```

Comment: You're forgetting the whitespace before the opening parentheses: `to_replace=r"\s\(.*\)"`

Comment: So simple and so true! Thank you @StevenRumbalski

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're forgetting the whitespace before the opening parentheses in your pattern: `to_replace=r"\s\(.*\)"`